# JWT токен с флагом httpOnly, как понять что клиент авторизирован?

Tags: javascript, cookie, jwt

Подскажите пожалуйста, как понять из `js`, что клиент авторизирован, если токен храниться в браузере с флагом `httpOnly`

Comment: Сделать запрос на сервер

Comment: это понятно, а есть варианты интереснее? что бы сразу понять что не стоит делать запроса на сервер, а надо редиректить на логин?